# Newline characters are getting converted into space in MicrosoftWord while performing MailMerge using Java

Tags: java, ms-word, newline, mailmerge

While performing mail merge using Java, new line characters are converted into space in Microsoft Word.So line breaks are lost after merge.Need to retain the line breaks in the text in MicrosoftWord after the merge is done.
Java code to perform mailmerge using IXDocReport:

```
package sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.IXDocReport;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.IContext;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.TemplateEngineKind;

public class Sample {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

              // 1) Load ODT file and set Velocity template engine and cache it to the registry           

              InputStream in= new FileInputStream(new File("sample.docx"));
              IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in, TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

              // 2) Create Java model context 
              IContext context = report.createContext();
              context.put("name", "new \n world");

              // 3) Generate report by merging Java model with the ODT
              OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("ODTHelloWordWithVelocity_Out.docx"));
              report.process(context, out);
       }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: I need help in retaining the line breaks in the WordDocument.Line breaks are getting converted into space.